# How to see/change vertex weight of vertex groups create by skin modifier?

Tags: modifiers, armature, vertex-groups

[image]i made an armature by skin modifier -> create armature.

Can i somehow see and change the vertex weights of the created vertex groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, this is a problem.  Most operations of weight paint won't even work if we try to weight paint a mesh that has no faces.  If we take a vert string and try to do a weight paint gradient, we won't even get an operator box, much less any change in weights.  And that's ignoring the fact that even if we could change the weights, we couldn't see how we changed them.

I haven't found a good solution to this, so here's the best (not very good) solution that I've found instead:

Add some faces to your string and use a mask modifier to get rid of them before the skin.  Once we have any faces whatsoever, even if they're being masked away, we can paint weights.  We still can't see them, not while the mask modifier is active, but we can paint them.

If we need to see our weights, we can disable the mask modifier temporarily.  This is far from ideal, but it's what I've got.

[image]

Comment: love that work around!! +1

Answer (score 2):

The modifier `Skin` creates an *Armature* from the edges of a mesh and additionally creates a vertex group for each bone.

You can see and edit the weight of those automatically created vertex groups when you switch the *object interaction mode* from **Object Mode** to **Weight Paint** in the upper left corner of the *3D Viewport*.

If you then select a *Vertex Group* in the *Properties* under *Object Data Properties*, the corresponding weight is displayed and you can repaint it.

[image]

**EDIT:** If you want to draw directly on the mesh that the modifier `skin` has created (for example, if you used only vertices as a starting point), then you would have to apply the modifier first:

[image]

**Alternative solution:**

Another way to influence the weights without applying the modifier `Skin` is to simply use the *Bone Envelopes* instead of *Vertex Groups*.

[image]

For this you would only have to change the value *Bind To* in the modifier of the *Armature* to *Bone Envelopes*.

[image]

Comment: Ähm….if I go to weight paint, I just see the edges….without weight paint. I know how to see „normal“ weight paint and I don’t see a skin modifier in your example. I just use a vertex, extrudes that, then added skin modifier and pressed create armature. i added a gif so can can see what i see/made ;)

Comment: Um... yes, that's right, with your screenshot it is all a bit better understandable ;-)

Comment: Ok, that’s sad. Hoped for another possibility.